# Rails 5 equivalent for this complex SQL query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a query working the way I want, by executing SQL directly, but am curious (just for my own learning purposes) if this same thing could be done in an ActiveRecord statement?

The part I'm struggling with the most is the COALESCE part of this query, which just makes sure that any NULL values from the LEFT JOIN are counted as zeros instead, to keep the summation in order.

Any ideas? I'm using Postgres.

```
SELECT Inventories.id, Inventories.name, Inventories.unit_of_measure,
    COALESCE(Sum(Stocks.count),0) as totalcount
    FROM Inventories
    LEFT JOIN Stocks
    ON Inventories.id = Stocks.inventory_id
    WHERE Inventories.property = 'material' AND Inventories.organization_id = #{current_organization.id}
    GROUP BY Inventories.id, Stocks.inventory_id
    ORDER BY totalcount ASC
    LIMIT(5)")
```

This is the closest I've gotten for an AR equivalent. When I try to add a sum or something like it, that's when it errors out.

```
@lowmaterials = current_organization.inventories.materials.left_joins(:stocks).group(:id, :inventory_id).order(count: :asc).limit(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select):

```
your_relation.select("column1, column2, COALESCE(1,2) AS column3").left_joins...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks -- didn't realize that was possible and so now I learned something. :)